# Using percent operators with double colon in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to use percent operators in R with the double colon notation?

For example:

```
foreach::%dopar%
foreach::"%dopar%"
```

Comment: Sure, you just can't use them as infix operators any more. `base::"%%"(5, 2)`. (Though using backticks is slightly better practice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though quotes work in the double colon case, when referring to an operator like this, you should enclose the operator in single back ticks:

```
foreach::`%dopar%`
```

This lets you refer to name anywhere that is not a legal identifier (a legal identifier starts with a letter and is made up of only letters and numbers and underscores).

```
`%%`(6, 4)  # Calling the mod operator in a weird way
`strange %^*&` <- 2  # Defining a weird variable
`strange %^*&` + `strange %^*&`  # Using the weird variable
```